# fluent nhibernate column not found on a deleted column

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

We removed a primary key and converted it into composite key. The property was removed from Model and Fluent Mapping. The field was deleted from DB. Now when we fire QueryOver on Submission, it triggers an update and the update throws `SQL Error: Invalid Column Name: 'SubmissionID'`

Previous

```
public class Submission{
  public virtual int SubmissionID{get;set;}
  public virtual int CandidateID{get;set;}
  public virtual int JobID{get;set;}
}
public class SubmissionMap:...{
  public SubmissionMap(){
    Id(x=>x.SubmissionID
  }
}
```

Changed to

```
public class Submission{
  public virtual Candidate Candidate{get;set;}
  public virtual Job Job{get;set;}
}
public class SubmissionMap:...{
  public SubmissionMap(){
    CompositeId()
     .KeyReference(x=>x.Job)
     .KeyReference(x=>.Candidate);

  }
}
```

After this change, Any update/insert on Submission is triggering a `SQL Error: Invalid SubmissionID column` .  We logged all the NHibernate SQL queries and none of them seem to have SubmissionID column.

As a temp fix, we have recreated the SubmissionID column, and the error goes away. We do have Redis 2nd level cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, are you still needing the `Submission` entity at all? It looks now as a pure [many-to-many](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-ofvalues) relationship between Candidate and Job.

It could then be mapped without an intermediate entity. (See last example on [this page](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/collections.html#collections-example) too.)

If you have additional properties on `Submission`, it is strange to give up its surrogate key for a composite one. This generally makes things harder for using an ORM. By example, you should now implement `Submission`'s [id as a component](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/components.html#components-compositeid). (See [this blog](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2010/06/30/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.html) for more explanation on why this, or read the whole [`composite-id` reference](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid).)

Now about your actual question and trouble: sorry, with the facts available in your question, I have no clue on how this could be possible. Do you have some old trigger in DB messing around?

Comment: DB schema dump does not show the column being refered anywhere. So does not seem to be any old trigger or for that matter any DB related issue. Will try to remove the redis cache and try to re-run and see if that helps. Thanks by the way for the suggestion and links on surrogate key.